# Adding values to dataframe columns based on value from a single column

Tags: python, regex, for-loop

I have a `DataFrame` with yearly kg/ha values in which the columns reach from 1950 to 2015. The first column are gridcodes (`gridcode_1`) reaching from 1 to 4. Every gridcode has a specific addition value I want to add to the kg/ha values of the other columns.

I tried to solve it via for loop and regular expression

```
for x in kilograms_dep2:
    if kilograms_dep2['gridcode_1'] == 1:
        kilograms[regex="[0-9]{4}"] + 2.7
    elif kilograms_dep2['gridcode_1'] == 2:
        kilograms_dep2[regex="[0-9]{4}"] + 16.04
    elif kilograms_dep2['gridcode_1'] == 3:
        kilograms_dep2[regex="[0-9]{4}"] + 2.7
    elif kilograms_dep2['gridcode_1'] == 4:
        kilograms_dep2[regex="[0-9]{4}"] + 0.75
```

but it would only result in syntax errors.

Here are the first few entries of the dataframe

```
 gridcode_1         1950_y         1951_y         1952_y         1953_y
          1    1477.273256    1477.273256    1477.273256    1477.273256
          2  523883.351859  523883.351859  523883.351859  523883.351859
          3    2698.864601    2698.864601    2698.864601    2698.864601
          4    6458.175014    6458.175014    6458.175014    6458.175014
```

so for `gricode_1 = 1` I want to add `2.7`, for `gridcode_1 = 2` I want to add `16.04` etc.

I'd appreciate every help for an elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
columns_list  = list(df.columns)
columns_list.remove('code')

df.loc[(df['code'] == 1 ),columns_list] = df.loc[(df['code'] == 1),columns_list] + 2.7

df.loc[(df['code'] == 2 ),columns_list] = df.loc[(df['code'] == 2),columns_list] + 16.04
```

result:

[image: Result]